# How can I get MIN and MAX consecutive dates by LOCATION over a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I need help to get the max and min date differences (in hours or days(float)) for each location. If the interval have only one date for that location, consider the difference from date above. The object is already sort by date(desc) and the rack is the same for all, can disregard. Thank you.

```
var data = [
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-11T13:53:51.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-08T12:36:51.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T12:36:27.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:44:40.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:43:33.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-08T10:42:55.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:41:55.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T10:41:18.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T09:47:42.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-07T10:24:56.000Z"}
]

var response = {
    42: {
        minHours : {
            value: 0.01,
          startTime: '2020-05-08T10:42:55.000Z',
          endTime: '2020-05-08T10:43:33.000Z'
        },
        maxHours : {
            value: 73.28,
          startTime: '2020-05-08T12:36:51.000Z',
          endTime: 'NOW() Current Datetime'
        }
   },
   41: {
        //do the same
   },
   40: {
        //do the same
   }
};
```

It's like a timeline, where I have to track the "rack".

1) From bottom to top: the rack arrived at site 40 on 2020-05-07T10: 24: 56.000Z and went to site 41 on 2020-05-08T10: 41: 55.000Z. So that rack remained 24.28 at location 40.

2) Now the rack arrived at site 41 on 2020-05-08T10: 41: 55.000Z and soon after it went to site 42 on 2020-05-08T10: 42: 55.000Z. So the time of stay at site 41 was 1 minute or 0.016 hours.

And so on. In the case of the first 2 lines, the rack arrived at location 42 on 2020-05-08T12: 36: 51.000Z and above it has no more locations, so it must compare with the current date and time.

Each comparison updates maxHours and minHours for that location if the difference is greater than maxHours or less than minHours.

Comment: Since your array is already sorted you just need to look for "How to compare dates in JS"

Comment: The array is sorted by date, not location. One location can have multiple "intervals" inside the input data, I need to find MIN and MAX intervals for each location. Sorry but I'am a beginner and the solution is not clear in my mind :(

Answer (score 0):

I added a possible solution by first storing the above date - just in case it's needed - then grouping the data and then computing the result. Maybe someone has an idea how to simplify it or make it more elegant.

I'm not sure, if minHours and maxHours are what you expected.

```js
let data = [
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-11T13:53:51.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-08T12:36:51.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T12:36:27.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:44:40.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:43:33.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-08T10:42:55.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:41:55.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T10:41:18.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T09:47:42.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-07T10:24:56.000Z"}
]

// Store the data above temporarily, then group by location;
let tmpResult = data.map((value, index) => {
  value.date = new Date(value.date);
  value.dateAbove = index > 0 ? data[index - 1].date : null;
  return value;
}).reduce((acc, val) => {
  (acc[val.location] = acc[val.location] || []).push(val);
  return acc;
}, {});

// Helper method.
let diffInHours = function(dt2, dt1) {
  var diff = (dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime());
  let hourConversion = 1000 * 60 * 60;
  diff /= hourConversion;
  return Math.abs(diff).toFixed(2);
}

// Create result object.
let result = {};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(tmpResult)) {
  let hasEnoughEntries = (value.length % 2 == 0);
  // What if there are only one or two entries for a location at all? Let's assume that min and max are the same then.
  let minIsMax = value.length < 3;
  // Use the last two entries for a location to compute the min hours. If there are not enough entries, use the date from above.
  let minHours = {
    startTime: new Date(value[value.length - 1].date),
    endTime: hasEnoughEntries ? value[value.length - 2].date : value[value.length - 1].dateAbove
  };
  minHours.value = diffInHours(minHours.startTime, minHours.endTime);
  
  // Use the first two entries for a location to compute the max hours.
  let maxHours = minIsMax ? maxHours : {
    startTime: value[1].date,
    endTime: value[0].date
  };
  maxHours.value = diffInHours(maxHours.startTime, maxHours.endTime);
  
  // Add it to the result object.
  result[key] = {
    minHours: minHours,
    maxHours: maxHours
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. For location 40, the maxHoursis from startDate: 2020-05-07T10:24:56.000Z to endDate: 2020-05-08T10:41:18.000Z.We have to get the first and last date for a location inside a interval (sequence of same location). Sorry for my english but do you understand what i want to say?

Comment: No, it's not clear. Maybe add the result for all times above in your example and try to explain for each example why it's happening that way. If I understand you correctly, the maxHours for 42 should be "2020-05-08T10:42:55.000Z" to "2020-05-11T13:53:51.000Z" then, which is different from your first example.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is always tidy there should be no problem with this.
The max is easy, take the last and the first.
The min I have compared the current with the last checked from that location.

```js
var data = [
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-11T13:53:51.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-08T12:36:51.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T12:36:27.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:44:40.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:43:33.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 42, date: "2020-05-08T10:42:55.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 41, date: "2020-05-08T10:41:55.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T10:41:18.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-08T09:47:42.000Z"},
    {rack: 1208, location: 40, date: "2020-05-07T10:24:56.000Z"}
];

var response = {};
var temp = {};


function getDiffDate(d1, d2){
  d1 = new Date(d1).getTime();
  d2 = new Date(d2).getTime();
  
  return Math.abs((d1 - d2)/1000 /60 /60 ).toFixed(2);
}


for(var i in data){
  
  if(! response[ data[i].location ]){ // First date
    response[data[i].location] = {
      maxHours: { endTime: data[i].date}
    };
    temp[data[i].location] = {init: data[i].date};
    
  }else{
    let r = response[data[i].location];
    let t = temp[ data[i].location ];

    r.maxHours.startTime = data[i].date; // Update Max
    r.maxHours.value = getDiffDate( r.maxHours.endTime, data[i].date);
    
    if(! t.last){ // Second date, set min
      t.last = data[i].date;
      
      r.minHours = {
        value: getDiffDate(t.last, data[i].date),
        endTime: t.init,
        startTime: t.last
      };
      
    }else{ // Compare Min
      if(getDiffDate(t.last, data[i].date) < r.minHours.value){
        
        r.minHours.value = getDiffDate(t.last, data[i].date);
        r.minHours.endTime = t.last;
        r.minHours.startTime = data[i].date;
      }
      t.last = data[i].date;
      
      
    }
    
  }
}

delete(temp);
console.log(response);
```